# $Z(T)=Z(\mathfrak a)$, $\mathfrak a$ the ideal generated by $T$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm studying by myself the first chapter of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry as a introduction to this subject. I don't know how to prove this claim $Z(T)=Z(\mathfrak a)$.

[image]

When we interpret the elements of $A$ as function, these functions are homeomorphisms? I couldn't prove that $Z(T)\subset Z(\mathfrak a)$ with the elements of $A$ being non-homeomorphic functions.

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure how homeomorphisms are involved in this case. Note that $Z(T)$ consists of points $P$ such that $f(P) = 0$ **for all $f \in T$**. See how $f, g \in T$ implies $(f + g)(P) = 0$ for all $P \in Z(T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where homeomorphisms come into play here. The inclusion $Z(T)\subset Z(\mathfrak a)$ is trivial. $Z(T)$ is the set of zeros of every function in $T$, while $Z(\mathfrak a)$ is the set of zeros of ever function in $\mathfrak a$. Since $T\subset \mathfrak a$, if $P$ is a zero of every function in $\mathfrak a$ then it is certainly a zero of every function in $T$.

Answer (score 1):

No, he is literally saying that the ring map $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to k^{(k^n)}$ given by sending a polynomial to its function is injective. There are many ways to see that. Since $k$ is alg. closed its infinite, and you can prove by induction that this statement is true for infinite fields. Or you can use the Nullstellansatz to note that any element of this kernel will be in the Jacobson radical of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which is trivially zero, for if $f$ is in the Jacobson radical, then $1+f\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\times=k^\times$, and thus $f$ itself is constant which forces it to be zero.